# Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode, unity3d

Сразу скажу что проблема решилась, но не знаю каким образом, соответственно может повториться.

Ошибка была при создании рабочей сборки для заливки в стор. Следуя советам из сети, ковырялся в code signing identity но там и так все как в советах. В общем полез я в keychain access посмотреть, ничего криминального не нашел, решил закрыть логин нажав на замочек. После этого делаю сборку, и в конце хкод запрашивает пароль для доступа к этому keychain access, при чем два раза подряд, после ввода, я получаю рабочую сборку. Хотелось бы знать реальную причину, т.к keychain access опять открыты, причем я их не открывал, но при сборке все равно запрашивает к нему пароль.

```
CodeSign /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-atxwevkcovvoadfzersqqcypppaj/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/alieninvasiontd.app
cd /Users/admin/Desktop/alieninvasion
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer: Irina Radzivil (AJK2P7Y3ZG)"
Provisioning Profile: "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *"
                  (3a9bf8e7-7df5-41bd-8e03-0f2d60fb3ae0)

/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign F068BCDD1C2FAD46BA87E438E93ED486A5418180 --entitlements /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-atxwevkcovvoadfzersqqcypppaj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/alieninvasiontd.app.xcent --timestamp=none /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-atxwevkcovvoadfzersqqcypppaj/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/alieninvasiontd.app

/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-atxwevkcovvoadfzersqqcypppaj/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/alieninvasiontd.app: errSecInternalComponent
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: why nor russian language?

Comment: Роман, пишите по-русски: вы находитесь на русскоязычном сайте.